# sharing foreign key Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I am trying to code this model using JPA + Hibernate 
[image]

here is my code for entity level one

**Entity level one**

```
@Entity
public class LevelOne {
@EmbeddedId
LevelOnePK levelOnePK;

@OneToOne(mappedBy = "levelOne")
private LevelTwo levelTwo;

private String valueCol;

//getters setters omitted 
}
```

**level one Pk**

```
@Embeddable
public class LevelOnePK implements Serializable {
private int idOne;
private int idTwo;
private int idThree;

//getters setters omitted 
}
```

**Entity Level two**

```
@Entity
public class LevelTwo {

@Id
private int LondId;

@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "lone_id_one")
@JoinColumn(name = "lone_id_two")
@JoinColumn(name = "lone_id_three")
private LevelOne levelOne;

@OneToOne(mappedBy = "levelTwo")
private LevelThree levelThree;

//getters setters omitted
}
```

**Entity Level three**

```
@Entity
public class LevelThree {

@Id
private int LondId;

@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name="l_one", referencedColumnName="lone_id_one", insertable=false, updatable=false)
@JoinColumn(name="l_two", referencedColumnName="lone_id_two", insertable=false, updatable=false)
@JoinColumn(name="l_three", referencedColumnName="lone_id_three", insertable=false, updatable=false)
private LevelTwo levelTwo;

private String valueCol;
//getters setters omitted
}
```

**What this code is doing**

this code is successfully mapping PK of Level one entity to Level two entity as foreign key.

**Where I am having problem**
I am unable to map composite foreign key of Level two entity into Level three entity and getting this error

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: referencedColumnNames(lone_id_one, lone_id_two, lone_id_three) of com.example.testQuestions.LevelThree.LevelThree.levelTwo referencing com.example.testQuestions.LevelTwo.LevelTwo not mapped to a single property
```

where I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Your model doesn't seem correct. The FK in LevelThree is a reference to LevelOne, not LevelTwo.

If you want LevelThree to have a reference to LevelTwo, the FK would be a single Long, as the PK of LevelTwo is a single Long